# not able to send arabic email with good characters

Tags: php

I want to send an arabic email using php, but it gives me others characters. How to send it with the arabic characters? This is my code:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{
$to = 'support@alkramlaundry.qa'; // Replace with your email

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'] . "\n\n" . 'Regards, ' . $_POST['name'] . '.';
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
{
    mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you aren't specifying any *Content-Type* header so the recipient will use some default encoding
2. values appended to the `$additional_headers` parameter of the `mail()` function need to be properly sanitized (or users [may inject additional headers](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68776))

Modified code (I assume the encoding is UTF-8):

```
$filterHeaderValue = function ($value) {
    return str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', trim($value));
};

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'] . "\n\n" . 'Regards, ' . $_POST['name'] . '.';
$headers =
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n" 
    . 'From: ' . $filterHeaderValue($_POST['name']) . "\r\n"
    . 'Reply-To: ' . $filterHeaderValue($_POST['email']) . "\r\n"
    . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()
;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($_POST['copy'] == 'on') {
    mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, email (or the smtp protocol) only accepts the first 7 bits in ascii. To enable support for other languages add the following field to your headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Here is the RFC backing:
[rfc5335](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5335)

Answer (score 0):

```
//header
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
                $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
                $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

                //plain text 
                $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
                $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
                $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));
```

Comment: try using this code for your email, you must change charset from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

First thing try:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: The docs don't mention this having any effect on the `mail()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset